# i am passing parameter from one function to another function in reactJs but result is coming null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my first file with function 1

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import { config } from '../../config/config.js';
class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentWillMount(){
      var obj = {
          campaign:campaignName,
          campaignId:campaignId,
          clientId:clientId,
          clientName:clentName,
          end:endDate,
          start:startDate,
          timeZone:new Date().getTimezoneOffset(),
          ReportName:'Chargebacks',
          widgetName:'Billing Cycle'
    }
     var resdata = ChartAPI.widgetApiCalls(config.apiUrl,obj);
     console.log(resdata );
  }
}
```

And this is another one with function 2

```
import axios from 'axios';
 function charts(){
     this.widgetApiCalls =  function(url,parmsobj){
        var byresspose=[];
        axios.get(url+"/reports",{params:parmsobj})
          .then(function(response){        
                for(var i in response.data){
                    byresspose.push({"label":"Billing Cycle"+" "+response.data[i].billingCycle,"value":response.data[i].total})
                }
                console.log(byresspose);
          });
          return  byresspose;
      };
 }
charts = new charts();
module.exports = charts;
```

What is the correct way to pass parameter from one function 1 to another function 2?

Comment: You mean you want to pass data to `charts` function from first file ?

Comment: Check this one also: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: import ChartsAPI from './charts.js'; acutally  i add this statement

Answer (score 1):

You need to import your `charts` module to your Dashboard Component source file:

```
import ChartsAPI from './charts.js';
```

And then you will be able to call it on componentWillMount:

```
 var chartsAPI = new ChartsAPI();
 chartsAPI.widgetApiCalls(config.apiUrl,obj).then(function(result) {
   var resdata = result;
   console.log(resdata);
 });
```

This also requires widgetApiCalls to return Promise:

```
this.widgetApiCalls =  function(url,parmsobj){
  return axios.get(url+"/reports",{params:parmsobj})
      .then(function(response){
            var byresspose=[];        
            for(var i in response.data){
                byresspose.push({"label":"Billing Cycle"+" "+response.data[i].billingCycle,"value":response.data[i].total})
            }
            console.log(byresspose);
            return byresspose; // this will come to the Dashboard `widgetApiCalls.then`
      });
  };
```

Comment: Accurate, but you could provide a little more detail about what the problem with his code was and why this fixes it. Specifically how promised are delayed and the value can't be returned traditionally

Answer (score 0):

callback

promise

async&await

i prefer the last one.
its a typical Asynchronous problem.

```
componentWillMount(){
          var obj = {
              campaign:campaignName,
              campaignId:campaignId,
              clientId:clientId,
              clientName:clentName,
              end:endDate,
              start:startDate,
              timeZone:new Date().getTimezoneOffset(),
              ReportName:'Chargebacks',
              widgetName:'Billing Cycle'
        }
         this.getData(config.apiUrl,obj)

      }
       async getData(url, obj) => {
            var resdata = await ChartAPI.widgetApiCalls(url,obj);
            console.log(resdata );
```

}

besides that i think that you don't need to defined chartAPI as a single module. 
just defined it in the component